# Featherlight lightbox gallery inside tabs deselects current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I currently have a very simple lightbox gallery inside a tabbed interface, however when clicking a photo from the gallery the currently selected tab is lost and no tab is selected.

So once the user closes the gallery image he doesn't see the current tab he was in.

I made a JSFiddle of this behaviour, try clicking the second tab and opening an image from the gallery, when closing it the currently selected tab is lost.

http://jsfiddle.net/urvmubxp/1/

The jquery for tabs and gallery is this:

```
$('.my-tabs li').click(function(){
    $(".tab").css('display','none');
    $(".my-tabs li").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    $('#'+this.childNodes[0].href.split('#')[1]).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
})
//set first tab active
$('.my-tabs li').eq(0).click();

$('.gallery2').featherlightGallery({
    gallery: {
        next: 'next »',
        previous: '« previous'
    },
    variant: 'featherlight-gallery2'
});
```

Is there something to do in order to keep consistency with tabs while using the gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a FL problem. Since you are using `$('.my-tabs li')` as a trigger for your tabs, and your gallery is nested as ul li too, the click on a gallery li causes your code to execute as well... you could use `$('.my-tabs > ul > li')` or asign a class to the tab-lis...